# How to filter the number on the gauge?

Tags: node-red, measurement, gauge

I have been facing some problems in Node Red. I was having some data for voltage, current and power. But the power data sometimes it keep going back to zero. So I want the gauge to stay at the most recent number that have shown. And only show zero, when multiple output have been always zero.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the smoothing node

[image]

This will generate a rolling average over a configurable set of values which should smooth out any random 0 values.